# Batch/VBS: asking for user input and with his data replace a string in a existent text file

Tags: batch-file

I need a vbs or batch to ask to user a value and after, put this value in a text file where I've to replace an existent value...

Currently, with a batch file, I can get user input and put it into a variable, but I can't find any feature to find a "part of a numeric string" (ip address) in to text file and replace it.

ES:

Let's say that the text file is "hosts.txt":

172.16.**16.1**       serverA

172.16. are constant value, I've to replace only the other 2 octet "**16.1**"...

All tools  that I know can't use "*" symbol in the search string options...

I can remove all ip address value or full line, but in this case I've to know the last value of ip address for find it and then add name record at the end of new value...

I cannot install anything into the clients, they are not under my administration.

Can you help me please?

Thanks, Robby.

Comment: Show us the code you've tried and tell us what it isn't working.

Comment: Hi @aphoria! Sorry, I've forgot my laptop at office, next monday I'll post it! But, my partial script working, now I don't know how can I use my variable (user input=ip address) to replace the "old" ip value!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for /f "tokens=1-4* delims=. " %A in (hosts.txt) do Echo %A.%B.newnum.newnum %E
```

the four octets are in %A, %B, %C, & %D and %E has servername

%A becomes %%A in a batch.