# How can I replace the old text in a file with new input using batch?

Tags: batch-file

I'm trying to replace the old salary that's stored in a text file with the new one as entered by the user.

The text file (employees.txt) I'm using looks like this: 101, Elon, Muskrat, 46, 1000000000

I've tried to do something similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25453845/batch-vbs-asking-for-user-input-and-with-his-data-replace-a-string-in-a-existen), but it's not working.

Can anyone explain to me what I'm missing?

```
:start
echo ------------- MAIN MENU -------------
echo 1. Search by Employee ID
echo 2. Exit

set /p choice=Please select a number: 

if %choice%==1 GOTO :employeeid
if %choice%==2 GOTO :exit
cls

echo INVALID INPUT!
echo Please select a number listed in the Menu options.
pause
cls
GOTO :start

:employeeid
cls
echo =========== Employee Pay Raise ===========
set /p id=Enter Employee ID: 
set /p pay=Enter the New Salary: 

set count=0

for /f "tokens=1-5 delims=," %%e in (Company\employees.txt) do (
if %%a==%id% (
%%a %%b %%c %%d %pay% > Company\employees.txt
)
)

set count=1

if %count%==0 echo Record Not Found! Please create the employee record 
first.
pause
cls
GOTO :start

:exit
GOTO :eof
```

Comment: If you're intending to have the output from your code to match that in your question, _(implied because you're trying to read from and write to the same file)_, why aren't you outputting the commas you need? Are you sure that you can read lines from a file whilst overwriting that same file without issue?

Comment: Also to output you need the `echo` command which is missing. writing to a new file you the else clause of the if to output the unchanged lines. Best enclose the whole for / in an additional pair of parentheses and redirect that, not the single echo's

Comment: Alright. I added the missing echo, the else statement, and wrapped the for in parentheses. It's made an improvement: I'm getting the pay output in my text file, the only problem is that it's not keeping the other information in my file, it's only replacing the salary -- it's showing up as: %a %b %c %d 2000000000. Is there any way to keep the other information already stored there?